# Maven error - cannot find symbol - on multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, multi-module

I downloaded the calendar from exoplatform from this link: https://github.com/exoplatform/calendar and I've trying to generate its war through the command mvn compile war:war. If I run mvn package or mvn install it works fine, but when I add the war:war, compile fails.

Here are the errors:

```
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[48,38] package org.exoplatform.calendar.model does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[49,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[50,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[51,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[52,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[53,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[54,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[55,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[56,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[57,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[58,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[59,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[115,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class CalendarService
[ERROR]   location: class org.exoplatform.webservice.cs.calendar.CalendarWebservice
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[116,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ExtendedCalendarService
[ERROR]   location: class org.exoplatform.webservice.cs.calendar.CalendarWebservice
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[120,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class CalendarService
[ERROR]   location: class org.exoplatform.webservice.cs.calendar.CalendarWebservice
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[134,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ExtendedCalendarService
[ERROR]   location: class org.exoplatform.webservice.cs.calendar.CalendarWebservice
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[330,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class CalendarEvent
[ERROR]   location: class org.exoplatform.webservice.cs.calendar.CalendarWebservice
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[330,72] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class FeedData
[ERROR]   location: class org.exoplatform.webservice.cs.calendar.CalendarWebservice
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[630,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class CalendarSetting
[ERROR]   location: class org.exoplatform.webservice.cs.calendar.CalendarWebservice
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/webservice/cs/calendar/CalendarWebservice.java:[630,67] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class CalendarEvent
[ERROR]   location: class org.exoplatform.webservice.cs.calendar.CalendarWebservice
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/calendar/ws/CalendarRestApi.java:[31,1] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/calendar/ws/CalendarRestApi.java:[32,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/calendar/ws/CalendarRestApi.java:[33,49] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service.Calendar does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/calendar/ws/CalendarRestApi.java:[34,45] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service.impl does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/calendar/ws/bean/CategoryResource.java:[22,40] package org.exoplatform.calendar.service does not exist
[ERROR] .../calendar-develop/calendar-webservice/src/main/java/org/exoplatform/calendar/ws/bean/CategoryResource.java:[33,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class EventCategory
[ERROR]   location: class org.exoplatform.calendar.ws.bean.CategoryResource
```

the main pom: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwWIlGx_c4cXM3puSVY2YTlDWE0/view?usp=sharing

the one which returns always returns errors: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwWIlGx_c4cXWlptTkp0VF95YlU/view?usp=sharing

I placed them in google drive due to the stack overflow char limit.

I have tried the solutions in stack overflow, like checking the dependencies doing mvn clean install, but whenever I add war:war It returns those errors.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Using `mvn install` or `mvn package` is the correct way to build your WAR. Why do you think that you need to run `mvn war:war` separately?

Comment: Ok @SteveC I tried what you said and despite trying it yesterday and not working, today it generated a war and it behaves accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Which branch did you checkout? Or did you add the `maven-war-plugin` configuration yourself? The `calendar-webservice` module is intended to be a `jar` that is included in `calendar-webapp`, which is the actual web application that is built as a WAR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The proper way to invoke the war goal is :

```
mvn compile war:war
```

Now, as you still see the errors, it appears that there could be dependency of one project to another. And, as the dependency couldn't be found in local repository (because you haven't installed that in local repo), the dependency couldn't be added in classpath and hence the errors.

Comment: This is not how you build WAR files. Maven builds a WAR file automatically when the packaging is set to `war` in the pom.xml.

Comment: Yes. Agree. But as the question owner asked, I gave the answer as he wanted.